# Supressing output with os.system()

Tags: python, shell, redirect, output

Why does the below MWE not redirect output to /dev/null.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
   os.system ( 'echo hello &>/dev/null' )
```

Comment: What do you mean? For me it prints no output, so it's redirected.

Comment: I'm not sure what an MWE is, and I don't know on what platform this doesn't redirect to /dev/null (it works for me on OS X 10.8 and some ancient linux distro), but… why are you using `os.system` in the first place? Use `subprocess` if you want control over what's happening—exactly as the `os.system` docs say.

Comment: My guess is MWE is "minimum working example"

Comment: Sorry, Minimum Working Example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure, but another (better) way to do it is:

```
from os import devnull
from subprocess import call

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open(devnull, 'w') as dn:
        call(['echo', 'hello'], stdout=dn, stderr=dn)
```

This opens `/dev/null` for writing, and redirects output of the spawned process to there.

---

**UPDATE based on comments from @abarnert**

In the specific case of `echo`, to get identically the same behavior you will want to use `shell=True` because otherwise it will call `/bin/echo`, not the shell builtin:

```
call('echo hello', shell=True, stdout=dn, stderr=dn)
```

Also, on Python 3.3+, you can do

```
from subprocess import call, DEVNULL

if __name__ == "__main__":
    call('echo hello', shell=True, stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL)
```

Comment: The only problem is that this runs `/bin/echo` rather than the shell builtin `echo`. So you probably want `call('echo hello', shell=True, stdout=dn, stderr=dn)`.

Comment: Also, in 3.3+, you can just use `stdout=DEVNULL` instead of having to open it manually, which is nifty.

Comment: @abarnert For `shell=True`, why use `'echo hello'` over `['echo', 'hello']`?

Comment: If you're using `shell=True`, Python is ultimately passing a string to the shell; if you give it a list, it has to figure out how to build the string. Sometimes this is handy (e.g., you're not sure how to quote something), but when you have a particular shell line you want run as-is, there's no point figuring out how to split it into a list for Python to re-join it into the same line you started with.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks, I haven't had a chance to use 3.3 yet, so I hadn't seen that.  That is a pretty smart feature to have in that module.